# What is ionice `none: prio 0` equivalent to?

Tags: linux, ionice

The ionice manual states that:

> Note that before kernel 2.6.26 a process that has not asked for an io
>   priority formally uses "none" as scheduling class, but the io
>   scheduler will treat such processes as if it were in the best effort
>   class. The priority within the best effort class will be dynamically
>   derived from the cpu nice level of the process: io_priority =
>   (cpu_nice + 20) / 5.
>
> For kernels after 2.6.26 with CFQ io scheduler a process that has not asked for an io priority inherits CPU scheduling class. The io
>   priority is derived from the cpu nice level of the process (same as
>   before kernel 2.6.26).

I am post 2.6.26, but that still leaves some open questions (I'm assuming CFQ):

1. What is the inheritance mapping for the scheduled class? Does TS SCHED_OTHER = Best Effort (io class 2)?
2. When using the ionice -p command to get the value, it returns `none: prio 0`. However, the formula mentioned in the ionice man would suggest that the same process (cpu nice of zero) would be `best-effort: prio 4` since (0 + 20) / 5 = 4.

So my assumption at this point is that `none: prio 0` = `best-effort: prio 4`, but I'm hoping someone can cite some kernel source in order to prove that this is authoritatively true.

Answer (score 0):

1)
From the docs [sched-design-CFS.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.txt):

> CFS stands for "Completely Fair Scheduler," and is the new "desktop" process
>   scheduler implemented by Ingo Molnar and merged in Linux 2.6.23.  It is the
>   replacement for the previous vanilla scheduler's SCHED_OTHER interactivity
>   code.

It seems you mixing up the O(1) scheduler with the CFQ io-scheduler.

So there are SCHED_{NORMAL, BATCH, IDLE} policies. IDLE does not have any priorities. And sched classes idle, best-effort and realtime.

2) Sadly you do not show what commands you typed. For example change init's io-scheduling to best-effort class

> # ionice -p 1
>     none: prio 0
>     # ionice -c2 20 -p 1
>     # ionice -p 1
>     best-effort: prio 4